# Is there a way to block certain SE site so I don't accidentally create profile there?

Tags: support

I just went through the profile deletion process (personal reasons) and I would like that my profile is not created automatically when I click a link to that site or something. Is there a possibility to mark specific SE site (Stack Overflow in my case) as "do not create profile there"?

Comment: I don't think there is such a way to do it. Your profile won't be created if you click a link on an SE site.

Comment: Step 1. Don't create an account when visiting sites on which you don't want an account. Step 2. See step one. Accounts are not created automatically, you can test this by visiting some random SE site. If you're super-worried, clear cookies.

Comment: @user568458 Ah. I had the wrong impression they are. I remembered as if it worked that way. Maybe wrongly.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of the "welcome back, we signed you back in" message? For that, you need a) an existing account on that site b) a logged in session / cookies (so if you want to take extra precautions, clear cookies, but I'm 99.9% sure it's unnecessary)

Comment: There are security programs, meant for children usually, to block certain web sites. Best bet is to install one of those, block Stack Overflow, and make sure you won't be tempted to uninstall the program.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no such a way, and no real reason to make it.

*No profile is created automatically*;  to create an account, you must:

- click "log in"
- enter your credentials
- moreover, *confirm* creating your account, otherwise it won't be created

So it's certainly not easy to create an account accidentally.

The only automatic process takes place when you already have an account and cookies are indicating *you've already logged to this account at least once on this computer* - then you'll be automatically logged in. But SE will never force you to create an account, even if you had already created it before and then requested deletion / deleted it.

Comment: I remember I automatically got 101 points and profile created when visiting not-yet-visited SE sites in the past. Was it changed?

Comment: @herby it was never the case.

Comment: @herby you still get a pop-up asking you to log in if you have no account; if you choose to log in then an account is auto-created with +100 reputation.